# c# Proper Form close checking and reopen back

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I'm a bit new to C# WPF. In below code, how do I do proper check that after form was closed/minimize, the form object can be reused. What I want to do is when form is closed open  it back using the same object? Kinda weird that after making it null and declaring the object also does not work?

```
private static SumByJournal sbj = null;    

public static void ShowSumByJournal()
    {
        if (sbj == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("null object");
            sbj = new SumByJournal();
            sbj.Activate();
            sbj.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            if (sbj.IsActive == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("active bro");
            }
            else
            {
                sbj.Activate();
                if (sbj.IsActive == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("active test");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("still not active");
                }
            }
            if (sbj.IsVisible == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("visible bro");
            }
            else
            {
                sbj.ShowDialog();
                sbj.Show();
                if (sbj.IsVisible == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("visible test");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("no visisable also.");
                }

            }
            if (sbj.IsInitialized == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("initlize");
            }

            sbj.ShowDialog();

            // so force it to null;
            sbj = null;
            sbj = new SumByJournal();
            sbj.Activate();
            sbj.ShowDialog();
            // still does not show ?? 
        }

    }
```

Comment: please clarify a bit. we are bit lost in the question.

Comment: When i run above code.. It prompt still not activate.

Comment: however the code above is not a usual practice of WPF, but could you post a working sample which can reproduce the same? As the code above is missing many bits (`SumByJournal` etc.) I may not able to reproduce the same.

Comment: To me the code look like derived from Winforms. also calling `Activate() before ShowDialog()` and `Show() after ShowDialog()` also look kind of unusual.

Comment: I use whatever property given.Ya previously i tested winform and it has checking upon dispose. I use showdialog instead of .show because focus issue on Microsoft Excel Addin.

Comment: for temp.. using hide with window style =none